# Web page div empty vs hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

When having 2 `<div>` elements both with fair amounts of graphic content and only one is shown at a time, is it better to hide then one not shown, or empty it and re-insert the html tags again?

When you hide, does everything stay in memory?

Comment: when you hide an element, it's only relevant to the screen render. code is still there, so it's also loaded in memory. to speed up things, you can load the unshown div as empty, and then populate it later via ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is most probably: it depends.

As humans, we have some orientation around what's required in terms of performance for different operation, but in this case when you are not sure, best practice is estimate and benchmark. The idea is to understand what's the compromise in every method:

First, and easier, is benchmark the memory impact of your hidden div. Note that **a hidden `<div>` is kept in memory, but is not rendered in page, thus having a smaller memory footprint than a rendered element**. Measuring this can be easily done, even simply using chrome task manager. Check multiple changing between the two, and measure the memory footprint when using each method. Is is really as major as you expected?

The second, a little more complicated: measure the impact to reloading and re-rendering on your client's system, and on the user experience of your app. Best is to use a WEAK machine, and maybe even a slow connection. Measure the delay created if any, if not using code and reporting, at least by your feel, and try to measure cpu peaking and process slowdown if any. Switch between the divs multiple times, in slow and rapid manners. Does it still feel slick?

In this case, I tend to guess the memory footprint is much smaller than you assume, but that's just my experience. I believe hiding and showing will require less effort than emptying and reloading.

That said, I'm certain after doing both, It'll probably become very clear to you what's the correct method for you. Hiding if the memory footprint is small, reloading if it's so large as to be worth the slow of reloading. Only you can measure and figure where's the line.

---

Side note: When hiding, best practice is to use `display:none;`. This ensures elements *are* removed from the render tree, which provides better performance than `opacity: 0;` / `visibility: hidden;`, although if you need one of those for specific functionality use them. If you don't need the functionality, then use `display: none;`. Also note that jQuery's `.hide()` uses `display: none;`, so it's best practice. From jQuery `.hide()` documentation:

> This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" )

---

*Sources:*

- How Web Browsers Work: [Render Tree Construction](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Render_tree_construction)
- jQuery documentation: [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- jQuery documentation: [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)